# Detecting simultaneous upload process

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cookies

Using php, I'm uploading files to two separate servers in a single process. Probably, that would take some time to complete.

Here, end user might open another window for another upload and number of such simultaneous process would increase. And consequently, that will affect currently running upload process to output undesired result.

So I'd like to disable multiple (or at least third) simultaneous file upload process.
When user try to upload file second or third time before completion of others, he should get warned.

Anyone please guide me on how to implement using php session cookies / Jquery Ajax   ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read the session_id and save somewhere a flag for that session until you complete the upload. Check the flag existence (or value count) before accepting a new upload. Once the upload has finished delete (or decrease the value) the flag. The storage can be db or a file in your server. Or instead of session_id use the user_id, unless you have anonymous uploads - which is not a very good idea anyway.

Comment: Any brief example please. I tried as u said before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy achieve this with Memcache since you would be working on multiple servers you need a central system you can use to track upload process

Example

```
$maxAllowedProcess = 1;
$uploadKey = "uploadProcess";
$memcache = new \Memcache();
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
$runtime = (int) $memcache->get($uploadKey);

if ($runtime >= $maxAllowedProcess) {
    echo "Sorry you can not upload at the moment tay again in 30mins" ;
} else {
    $runtime ++;
    $memcache->set($uploadKey, $runtime);

    // Stat upload Process on any server
    // example move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination) ;;

    $runtime = (int) $memcache->get($uploadKey);
    $runtime = ($runtime < 1) ? 0 : $runtime ++;
    $memcache->set($uploadKey, $runtime);

    echo "Upload Sucessfull" ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Baba. but I'm on a share host. so installing Memcache module is not possible. one file send to remote server using Curl and other is to parent server where php is executing.

Comment: You can sill use another storage but the same concept